# Factor Theorem given two factors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

The function $f(x)= ax^3-x^2+bx-24$ has three factors. Two of these factors are $x-2$ and $x+4$. 
Determine the values of a and b and then solve for $f(x)$. Please give an algebraic solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I had already begun with this approach by evaluating the equationd at f(2) and f(-4) but I am more having trouble with isolating my variables.  Since when I break them down I am still left with for example 64a=-4b-8, which to get a by itself I would have to divide by 64, but how is the -4b-8/64 going to work as a value of a?  Or have I made a mistake here?

Comment: I added a bit. Take a look.

Comment: So would b = 14-4a?

Comment: Yes. Could you please comment at my answer? (you'll find 'add a comment' there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT : By [the factor theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem), we have $$F(2)=a\cdot 2^3-2^2+b\cdot 2-24=0\tag1$$$$F(-4)=a\cdot (-4)^3-(-4)^2+b\cdot(-4)-24=0\tag2$$
Now, you can solve these for $a,b$.

$$(1)\Rightarrow 8a+2b=28\Rightarrow 4a+b=14.$$
$$(2)\Rightarrow -64a-4b=40\Rightarrow -16a-b=10.$$

Comment: Sorry. I haven't had a lot of experience with this website.  I'm not sure where you got the 40 from though.  When I substituded (-4) for x, I got -64a+16-4b-24, which when you rearrange it, it becomes -64a-4b-8.

Comment: @Ashton: Note that $-64a\color{red}{-}16-4b-24=0$ because $-(-4)^2=-16$. So, $-64a-4b-40=0\Rightarrow -64a-4b=40$.

Comment: Oh okay, I see that now.  Thankyou.  I will try this again.

Comment: @Ashton: You are welcome.

Comment: So this what I got now after retrying: -64a-4b-40=0

Comment: 40= -64a-4b , 40+4b=-64a  , -0.625-0.0625b=a

Comment: @Ashton: Don't divide by $-64$. You have $b=14-4a$. So, you can have $40=-64a-4b\Rightarrow 40=-64a-4(14-4a)$. Then, solve this for $a$.

Comment: Oh interesting, I never thought of that since I have never encountered a question where I would have to do that.  That will make it much easier though however.

Comment: With that I got a=-2, so then I can put in my values for a and b into the equation and solve for f(x)?

Comment: @Ashton: Yes, exactly. Good job.

Comment: Thankyou very much! I had been uncertain about that question for a while.  We were given a long sheet of questions that I did fine with until that one.  I'm also generally a nervous/shy person, so I was afraid to ask my teacher for help on it.  Thankyou!

Comment: @Ashton: You are welcome! Good luck!. By the way, don't forget to accept an answer you like to let them know that this question is finished.

Comment: Wait, haha sorry.  so then I go back to the original equation and put in my values so: (-2)x^2 -x^2 + (14 - 4(-2))-24, I'm just asking if this form is correct to make sure, I'm slightly intimidated by it.

Comment: The answer should be $f(x)=-2x^3-x^2+22x-24.$

Comment: I have that, except for the x was missing on the 22.  I had forgotten to include it.  Though now I notice it. :) haha

Comment: So this would be answer to the whole question, I do not need to factor it further? Because if I did that I could get the x-intercepts and isolate for the x terms.  But it does not seem to ask for them, those would be factors.

Comment: @Ashton: No need to factor it. The answer is $f(x)=-2x^3-x^2+22x-24$.

Comment: Okay, awesome.  Again thankyou for the help.  I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @Ashton: Do you know how to accept an answer? Check the mark where the number 3 exists.

Comment: @Ashton: Thank you for your acceptance.